# How to safely remove default folders?

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, xubuntu, directory, filemanager

In the File Manager (Xubuntu 12.04), I can see some default folders which I don't need (like Videos, Music, ...). Is it safe to remove them or might programs not work properly afterwards (like on Mac OS X where I tried that once)?

I found this thread on Ubuntu Forums [How to permanently delete folders "Music, Videos, Documents,...." (through Nautilus)](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1851832) . Is this the way one should remove these folders?

Comment: What folders are you talking about?

Comment: he's probably talking about the once in /home/$USER (ie. Desktop, Downloads) @alvar

Comment: Sorry, I completely forgot (I updated the post). Indeed, I meant precisely those in `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`

Comment: It's better to state the folders in the question rather than linking to an external site.

Comment: Thanks, I stated them. The link is necessary for my last question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. See [post #7](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=11295941&postcount=7) in [your link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1851832).

Backup the config file (optional):

```
cp ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs.bak
```

Edit the file by commenting out unnecessary entries:

```
vim ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
```

Run update command:

```
xdg-user-dirs-update
```

**DO NOT REMOVE `XDG_DESKTOP_DIR`**

Comment: This does *not* do what OP asked. `xdg-user-dirs-update` will simply update `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` (and might, in particular, override some of OP's modifications from before), not create/rename/remove any directories as the above instructions suggest. See `man xdg-user-dirs-update` for information on what it does exactly. The actual answer should be: Simply remove the folder. (Running `xdg-user-dirs-update` is not necessary as it will be run upon the next user login, anyway, see `~/.config/user-dirs.conf`.)

Comment: Doesn't work -- even if you don't run the update command, it gets updated upon the next reboot. There must be a more fundamental file in which these directory names are kept.

Comment: See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285313/how-to-customize-add-remove-folders-directories-the-places-menu-of-ubuntu-13) for a working solution. If you also want to remove the folders from the home directory, edit user-dirs.defaults, or make a copy of it in .config and edit there (for your local user).